# Fix screen recording in a prerecorded video

Tags: video, editing

Since I can't find any answers elsewhere, I may as well ask here – I have a video in which there is screen tearing present in the recording, not having anything to do with my monitor or graphics card. Is there a way to fix this? I am familiar with FFmpeg and have access to Adobe editors if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your video is 640×360. Then you may use the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter

```
ffmpeg -i "BTT jump - monk break 10.300.mp4" -vf crop=506:284:134:0 output.mp4
```

to cut out unused (black) part from the left and the bottom of video.

*Note:*
The [cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect) filter gave a little different values for width, high and x, y coordinates of the upper left corner:

> ```
> ... w:496 h:272 x:140 y:8 ...
> ```

i.e. it recommended to use `crop=496:272:140:8`. I manually adjusted these values.

Original:

[image]

Cropped:

[image]

Comment: I know how to crop the video; that's not the problem. I need to fix the screen tearing